# Highcharts Speedometer, dataLabel for mileage counter

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gauge, meter

There are several examples with the Speedometer in Highcharts.

Is there a way, to show an additional **dataLabel only**, without dial in the gauge?
It could show a trip recorder, mileage counter or day counter.

I tried additional series and dataLabels, but could not get it running.

http://jsfiddle.net/uqa0t3xw

```
series: [{
    name: 'mileage counter',
    data: [],
    dataLabels: {
        x: 0, y: 20,
        format: '{y:.0f} km',
    }
}]
```

Comment: are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/edLHB/7/)?

Comment: @TechnoCrat Thank you for the test, that's the same I got with several series in one gauge. I think the hints **Ondkloss** wrote are helpful: "transparent" and "overlapping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an additional data label by adding another series and hiding the dial you can do so by setting the color of the dial to `"transparent"` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqa0t3xw/4/)):

```
series: [
// Our "hidden" series
{
    name: 'mileage counter',
    data: [0],
    dataLabels: {
        x: 0, y: 50,
        format: '{y:.0f} km',
    },
    dial: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
},
// ... Other series
]
```

Also note how the `y` value has to be big enough to not overlap with the other data labels. If it overlaps it will be hidden, since gauge has `allowOverlap: false` by default. Alternatively you could set that to `true`, but overlapping might not be pretty.

It should be noted that this can also be solved by creating your own `div` and placing it in the correct spot or perhaps copying the data label from the first series and moving it slightly.

Comment: @TechnoCrat **Fantastic**, transparent and overlapping seem to be the essential hints. But I hope, the dial-animation is disabled when being transparent. Otherwise it would invisibly rotate several thousand times. What do you think? http://jsfiddle.net/uqa0t3xw/5/

Comment: **Sorry @Ondkloss**, I wanted to address you with this post. http://jsfiddle.net/uqa0t3xw/6/

Comment: If you just remove the coloring it does seem to rotate quite a bit, but without noticable slowness or performance issues for me. Either way, you could do all your updating of that particular point without animation. The third parameter of the `update` function is `animation`. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uqa0t3xw/7/).

Comment: @Vinz, not sure if you got notified of my comment.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. This is from the api: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update
There you can test the animation=false. This works as expected. Thank's for your help.